# Are infinite std::chrono::duration objects legal?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++-chrono

Is it legal to make and use `std::chrono::duration<double>`'s with an infinity as the contained value, like so?

```
std::chrono::duration<double>{ std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() };
```

Will it behave 'like I expect', keeping an infinite value when adding or subtracting with other durations?

I've dug through cppreference but the only thing I've found discussing the question is the page on `duration_cast` noting that:

> Casting from a floating-point duration to an integer duration is subject to undefined behavior when the floating-point value is NaN, infinity, or too large to be representable by the target's integer type. Otherwise, casting to an integer duration is subject to truncation as with any static_cast to an integer type.

which seems to imply that it's legal, but only in a backhanded sort of way.

(I'm using the type to represent a "Please wake me up in X seconds" way, and positive infinity is a useful sentinel to represent "I really don't care when I wake up")

Comment: *The rule for determining the result of an operation that has infinity as an operand is simple: replace infinity with a finite number x and take the limit as x goes to infinity.* from [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#918)

Comment: @Yola I'm not doing arithmetic with doubles, though, I'm doing it with `std::chrono::duration<double>`, which might have its own opinions about what the domain and range of operations should be. Particularly because `std::chrono::duration<some integral type>` is a much more common use case for the template.

Comment: You do. `constexpr duration& operator+=(const duration& d); Effects: As if by : rep_ += d.count();` and `constexpr rep count() const; Returns: rep_.` And in your case `_rep` is `double`.

Comment: Also consider whether your design would be better with a separate state variable for "don't care" rather than a distinguished value. If you are using doubles to represent time I doubt you are concerned about compactness. 
I am curious what your reason for wanting to use floating point values to represent times is. I can't think of a good use myself unless you need to cover both a huge range and have higher precision for shorter durations. If its just higher precision you want you might consider std::chrono::microseconds instead.

Comment: Floating point is more convenient than a quantised value in a lot of ways and the code is interoperating with some stuff that thinks of time as a floating-point second count (i.e. not std::chrono, just a double).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The value `infinity` for `std::chrono::duration<double>` will behave as you expect with arithmetic operators.

#### `std::chrono::duration<double>` is perfectly fine

[[time.duration]](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.duration) defines the conditions existing on `Rep` for `template<class Rep> std::chrono::duration` and `double` is explicitly allowed (per [[time.duration]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.duration#2.sentence-1)), no special value disallowed:

> `Rep` shall be an arithmetic type or a class emulating an arithmetic type.

#### `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` is perfectly fine

[[time.duration.arithmetic]](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.duration.arithmetic) and [[time.duration.nonmemberdefine]](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.duration.nonmember) define the behaviour of the arithmetic operators on `duration`. For each `operator♦` and given two `duration` objects `A` and `B` holding the `double` values `a` and `b`, `A♦B` effects as `a♦b` would. For instance for `+`:

> In the function descriptions that follow, `CD` represents the return type of the function. `CR(A, B)` represents `common_­type_­t<A, B>`.
>
> ```
> template<class Rep1, class Period1, class Rep2, class Period2>
>   constexpr common_type_t<duration<Rep1, Period1>, duration<Rep2, Period2>>
>     operator+(const duration<Rep1, Period1>& lhs, const duration<Rep2, Period2>& rhs);
> ```
>
> *Returns: `CD(CD(lhs).count() + CD(rhs).count())`.*

This explicitly means that the following will behave as expected:

```
const double infinity = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
std::chrono::duration<double> inf{ infinity };
std::chrono::duration<double> one{ 1.0 };
inf + one; // as if std::chrono::duration<double>{ infinity + 1.0 };
```

Answer (score 6):

The [`duration_values`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.traits) trait has a `max()` value for that purpose:

```
    std::chrono::duration<double>::max();
```

Don't use `infinity`. Should you happen to convert such a duration to an integer-based type in the future, you can end up with UB.

Comment: I disagree: `std::chrono::duration<double>::max()` will return, by definition, `DBL_MAX`. But _nothing_ says it implies infinity is disallowed.

Comment: @YSC - I never said `infinity` is disallowed. I just say you should be extra careful if you use it. But why would you want to write fragile code like that?

Comment: You wrote _"for that purpose"_. The purpose of answering OP questions? OP questions being "is infinity allowed and work as expected?". What you write has value, but it doesn't answer the question I think.

Comment: The purpose is "*I really don't care when I wake up*".

Comment: `std::chrono::duration<double>::max()` doesn't really have the right properties to act as a (convenient) sentinel; the use of infinity allows some adding/subtracting of values to the returned value without making it no longer the sentinel value.

Comment: I think the place where inf acts differently to max is if Period (the second operand of duration) is not = 1. Granted, it is natural to use just 1 (second) with double, but it is possible to define a period of day, or microsecond. When you convert between double durations with different periods, the value max() ***WILL NOT BE PRESERVED***, while the value inf will be preserved, and be available for later comparisons.

Comment: Looking at the implementation of std::chrono::duration_cast:    `__cast(const duration<_Rep, _Period>& __d)
   {
     typedef typename _ToDur::rep   __to_rep;
     return _ToDur(static_cast<__to_rep>(static_cast<_CR>(__d.count())
       * static_cast<_CR>(_CF::num)
       / static_cast<_CR>(_CF::den)));
   }`
you can see that it takes no account of max() and is just as likely to overflow doing a type conversion or scaling as inf.

Comment: When a float overflows, the result is `inf` (implementation-defined). But when `inf` is cast to a `long`, UB happens. And because it's wrapped, it becomes difficult to track when that actually happens. That's all I'm saying. I personally would use nether inf nor max(), just some very high value like 100 years (don't plan to live longer than that).

Comment: @rustyx why would you cast that `inf` in any integer type in the first place? Only MSVC implements `duration` with an underlying `long`, and all know `std::chrono` is broken anyway on MSVC.

Comment: @YSC Recent versions of VS (at least VS2017, maybe VS2015?) have a much-improved `std::chrono`, at least in my experience so far. `high_resolution_clock` is now implemented using `QueryPerformanceCounter`, so it's monotonic and relatively high precision (we're getting ~300-400ns of access latency and precision)

Comment: @JamesPicone And let me guess, it does not use an underlying integer type anymore, right?

Comment: @YSC 64-bit integral nanosecond count.

Comment: @JamesPicone still broken then.